# Variable has two values simultaneously?

Tags: c++, pointers

I ran into this example online and I can't figure out how it works for the life of me.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int const a = 1;
    int* pa = (int*) &a;
    *pa = 2;
    printf("%p %d %p %d", (void*) &a, a, (void*) pa, *pa);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it on my machine, I get:

```
0xffffcc04 1 0xffffcc04 2
```

Which means that the memory location `0xffffcc04` has value 1 and 2 simultaneously??? Is the compiler optimizing away `a`, or am I missing something?

P.S. when I run this in debug, `a` and `*pa` are 2...

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of undefined behavior! You can't do that.

Comment: The code just has a bug. If you fix the bug, the mystery will go away.

Comment: And how many warnings did this code output when you turned on warnings?  You always compile with warnings on right?

Comment: The compiler is optimizing away `a`. Since you declared it as `const`, it knows it can replace `a` with `1` anywhere it sees it.

Comment: Of course it isn't code in c++, it's code in C and you don't use `#include <iostream>`

Comment: It doesn't pay to lie to the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing a `const`-value yields undefined behaviour, and the "mysterious" output is just such undefined behaviour. 
It is actually needless to investigate on why a behaviour in the world of undefined behaviour is as it is then. But in your case it is probably not using `a` as you declare it as `const`, so the compiler "knows" the value and may decide not to access the variable.
Just for showing something curious, try:

```
int main()
{
    volatile int const a = 1;
    int* pa = (int*) &a;
    *pa = 2;
    printf("%p %d %p %d", (void*) &a, a, (void*) pa, *pa);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the constructive answer, makes perfect sense. This is a bit of a tangent, but what would be the purpose of a volatile const? Would it be to, for example, set up read-only access to some sort of hardware?

Forgive me if I'm breaking the rules, I just started C++ about a month ago :)

Comment: yes, read only access to hardware would be a use case. But actually I wanted to show how compiler optimisations influence the percieved behaviour (even if undefined :-) )

Comment: Thanks for the help!